# How to return data from java to javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I wrote native code in java to get account info of gmail account.

While simply returning from 1st method, i was getting undefined in javascript. Where in 2nd method i am returning email address through callback to js which works perfectly.

**1st method :-**

*java code :-*

```
@ReactMethod
    public String getUsername() {
        AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(myContext);
        Account account = getAccount(accountManager);
        if (account == null) {
           return null;
        } else {
            return account.name;
        }
    }
```

*RN side :-*

```
let email  = NativeModules.GetInfo.getUsername();
alert(email) //undefined
```

---

**2nd method :**

*java code :-*

```
@ReactMethod
    public void getUsername(Callback errorCallback, Callback successCallback) {
        AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(myContext);
        Account account = getAccount(accountManager);
        if (account == null) {
            errorCallback.invoke("not found");
        } else {
            successCallback.invoke(account.name);
        }
    }
```

*RN side :-*

```
NativeModules.GetInfo.getUsername((error)=> {
                alert(error)
            },
            (email)=> {
                alert(email) //works perfect
            }
        )
```

Comment: and the question is ?

Comment: simply returning in 1st method yields undefined in javascript. i had to use callback for that. any idea what's wrong with the first method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to handle it with a Promise. Change your method signature to

```
public void getUsername(final Promise promise){
    ...
    promise.resolve("username");
}
```

and in your javascript

```
...
let username = await NativeModules.GetInfo.getUsername();
```

Comment: can't we just simply return data?

Comment: My guess is no, at least, there is nothing in react-native docs that seem to imply it.